# How to print code 3 of 9 barcode to normal printer in win form application

Tags: vb.net, printing, barcode, barcode-printing

I want to print code 3 of 9 barcode from my vb.net aplication to printer. 
i want to check wether this is printing to correct format or not.
i am calling this function in my print button click, how i can pass this value to my normal printer, i want to just print this A4 sheet

```
Dim PrinterName As String
Dim Printlabel As New MyPrinter
PrinterName = "Sharp AR-M318 PCL 6"
Dim k As String = info
Dim stchar As String = String.Empty
Dim addStar As String = "*"
Dim full As String = addStar & info & addStar

        info = full
        Dim bc As Drawing.Bitmap = New Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1)
        'Dim myf As Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular) ', GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Dim ft As Drawing.Font = New Drawing.Font("Free 3 of 9 Extended", 60, Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Dim g As Drawing.Graphics = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bc)
        Dim infoSize As Drawing.SizeF = g.MeasureString(info, ft)
        bc = New Drawing.Bitmap(bc, infoSize.ToSize)
        g = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bc)
        g.Clear(Drawing.Color.White)
        g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel '
        For Each chr As Char In info
            stchar &= chr.ToString & " "
        Next

        g.DrawString(stchar, ft, New Drawing.SolidBrush(Drawing.Color.Black), 2, 3)
        g.Flush()
        ft.Dispose()
        g.Dispose()
        Return bc
        Printlabel.prt(bc, PrinterName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using Zen Barcode. This is much easier to handle and you are not dependend that the font is installed on the PC where your software runs. Also you don't have to bother with checksums.

Here you will find the nuget-package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework/